# Objective-C: Change UIImageView in Custom Cell change different cell images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a custom cell on `UITableView` with multi Section and i’m added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `UIImageView` for change it when the image is selected but When I select the image other's images in different cell are selected as well.

This is the code for the TableView datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FilterCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *text = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:ROW_TITLE];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ROW_IMAGE];

    NSDictionary *item = [results objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *string = [item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_name];
    [text setText:((string != [NSNull null])? string : @"")];


    if ([[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_status] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]])
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked"]];
    else
        [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked"]];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self

        [image setTag:indexPath.row];
        [image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];                                                                              action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];

    if([self tableView:tableView
             canCollapseSection:indexPath.section]){ // EXPANDABLE ROW

         if(!indexPath.row){// HEADER
            // SET ACCESORIES
            if([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
                [cell setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menos"]]];
            else
                [cell setAccessoryView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mas"]]];

        [image setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        //Remove checked option from a cell
           for(UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture in cell.gestureRecognizers)
                [cell removeGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


        }else{// SUB ROWS
            NSArray *subValues = [item objectForKey:PARAM_STRUCT_SUBELEMENTS];
            NSDictionary *detail = [subValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row -1];
             //REASING VALUES TO SUB VALUES
            if(detail && [detail isKindOfClass:[City class]]){
                City *currentCity = (City *)detail;
                [text setText:[currentCity name]];
            }

            [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
            [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
            [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

        }

    }else{//ROWS CHECKED OPTION

        [cell setAccessoryView:nil];
        [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    }

    return cell;
}

</code>
</pre>
```

This is the code for the TableView datasource method didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *data = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if([self tableView:tableView
        canCollapseSection:indexPath.section]){
        if(!indexPath.row){// EXPANDABLE
            // only first row toggles expandaed/collapse
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
            BOOL currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
            NSInteger rows;

            NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];

            if(currentlyExpanded){
                rows = [self tableView:tableView
                 numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];
            }else{
                [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                rows = [self tableView:tableView
                 numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            }

            for(int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
                NSIndexPath *tmpIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                                inSection:section];
                [tmpArray addObject:tmpIndexPath];
            }

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            if(currentlyExpanded){
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mas"]];
            }else{
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menos"]];
            }


        }else{// Detail

        }

    }else{ // Normal Row
        //[]
    }}
```

This is the code for the TableView datasource method fro the UITapGestureRecognizer

```
    - (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UITableViewCell *cellView = (UITableViewCell *)[recognizer view];
    UIImageView *switchImageView = nil;


    for (UIView *item in [[[cellView subviews] firstObject] subviews]) {
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && ((UIImageView *)item).image != nil) {
            switchImageView = (UIImageView *)item;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (switchImageView == nil) {
        for (UIView *item in [[[[[cellView subviews] firstObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews]) {
            if ([item isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && ((UIImageView *)item).image != nil) {
                switchImageView = (UIImageView *)item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSDictionary *item = [results objectAtIndex:switchImageView.tag];

    if ([Utility image:switchImageView.image
             isEqualTo:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_UNCHECKED]]) {

        if ([[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_action] isEqualToString:JSONResp_sortings]) {
            [delegate didCheckFilter:item
                          withStatus:YES];
        } else if ([[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_action] isEqualToString:JSONResp_filters]) {
            [switchImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_CHECKED]]; //change to a selected image

            [delegate didCheckFilter:[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_type]
                          withStatus:YES];
        }
    } else {
        if ([[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_action] isEqualToString:JSONResp_filters]) {
            [switchImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_UNCHECKED]];

            [delegate didCheckFilter:[item objectForKey:JSONResp_common_type]
                          withStatus:NO];
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. You need to make sure that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` correctly sets/resets all cell attributes

Answer (score 0):

While declaring the UITapGestureRecognizer on particular cell assign the tag as

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

and in your handler do like this

```
- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
UITableViewCell *cellView = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:recognizer.tag inSection:0]];
// your stuff
}
```

Hope this Helps!